# Python groupby issue

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Sample Raw data:

```
 DATE,DUR,TYPE
2013-10-11,15,PTG
2013-10-11,110,PV1
2013-10-11,122,RG1
2013-10-11,31,SG2
```

I am using python and I have a list (below is a sample)

```
list=[['10/15/2013', 'PTG', '19'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'PV1', '219'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'PVG', '13'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'RG1', '112'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'SG2', '438'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'PV1', '110'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'PVG', '9'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'RG1', '25'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'SG2', '48']]
```

I want the list (aggregated result) to be something like below:

```
         #Date      PV1 PVG RG1 SG2
result=[[10/15/2013,219,13,112,438],
        [10/12/2013,110,9,25,48]]
```

Below is my code:

```
from itertools import groupby
datetime1=range(10/11/2013,10/15/2013)
chunks=[]
for datetime in datetime1:
    count=[datetime]
    path='/user_home/w_andalib_dvpy/sample_data/3d_sample.csv'
    file=open(path)
    data=csv.reader(file)
    table=[row for row in data]
    for key,group in groupby(table,lambda x: x[2]):
        total=0
        for item in group:
            total +=int(item[1])
        if   item[2]=='PV1':
             count[1]=total
        elif item[2]=='PVG':
             count[2]=total
        elif item[2]=='RG1':
             count[3]=total
        elif item[2]=='SG2':
       print count
    chunks.append(count)
```

But I am not getting any result.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pivottable/0.8)

Comment: When I type `10/11/2013` in a shell I get `0`.  Without quotes this is a sequence of integer divisions.  So your range is empty.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of this you should really look into pandas, start with `pandas.read_csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary like this and extract its values list:

```
list=[['10/15/2013', 'PTG', '19'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'PV1', '219'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'PVG', '13'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'RG1', '112'],
     ['10/15/2013', 'SG2', '438'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'PV1', '110'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'PVG', '9'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'RG1', '25'],
     ['10/12/2013', 'SG2', '48']]

my_dict = {'10/15/2013': ['10/15/2013'],  '10/12/2013': ['10/12/2013']}

for elem in list:
    my_dict[elem[0]].append(elem[2])

print my_dict.values()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) It worked :)
Also, can you look at my above code? Can you point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: Change datetime1=range(10/11/2013,10/15/2013) to datetime1=[10/11/2013,10/15/2013] because it is empty list. Write what your data variable looks like so that
I can understand rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to collect the rows into a dictionary, and then convert that data into the new list of lists.  I don't think the extra machinery of `groupby` helps here.

```
d={}  # initial a dictionary
for l in list:
    a = d.get(l[0],{}) # load each item into the dictionary
    a[l[1]]= int(l[2])
    d[l[0]]=a
result = [[k,v['PV1'],v['PVG'],v['RG1'],v['SG2']] for k,v in d.items()]
```

The dictionary looks something like:

```
{'10/12/2013': {'PV1': 110, 'PVG': 9, 'RG1': 25, 'SG2': 48},
 '10/15/2013': {'PTG': 19, 'PV1': 219, 'PVG': 13, 'RG1': 112, 'SG2': 438}}
```

`result` looks like:

```
[['10/12/2013', 110, 9, 25, 48], 
 ['10/15/2013', 219, 13, 112, 438]]
```

Don't forget that '10/12/2013' is a string, not a number.  You can't treat like a number until you convert it to a `date`.